# Multithreaded number printer in ordered manner

Tags: c++, multithreading, interview-questions

On recent interview I was asked to write program that print "Zero" and "One" to stdout from different threads, but in ordered manner:

```
zero
one
zero
one
zero
one
...
```

Now I decided to write more generalized solution and this is my first attempt:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

struct OrderNumberPrinter
{
    OrderNumberPrinter(const std::initializer_list<std::string>& list)
        : m_len(list.size())
        , m_cv(list.size())
    {
        size_t num = 0;
        for(auto it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); ++it, ++num)
        {
            m_workers.emplace_back([this, num, message = *it](){
                while(true)
                {
                    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_printLock);
                    m_cv[num].wait(lock, [this, num](){ return m_current == num; });
                    std::cout << message << "\n";
                    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
                    ++m_current;
                    if (m_current == m_len)
                    {
                        m_current = 0;
                    }
                    m_cv[m_current].notify_one();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    ~OrderNumberPrinter()
    {
        for(auto& w: m_workers)
        {
            if (w.joinable())
            {
                w.join();
            }
        }
    }
private:
    int m_len = 0;
    int m_current = 0;
    std::vector<std::condition_variable> m_cv;
    std::mutex m_printLock;
    std::vector<std::thread> m_workers;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    OrderNumberPrinter printer = {"zero", "one", "two", "three"};
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're using a c++20 compiler, I'd suggest [`std::basic_osyncstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_osyncstream).

Comment: @Edward Thank you will try it. I think in this case it would be better to use C++11/14/17

Answer (score 2):

Here are some things that may help you improve your program.

### If it has private members, it should be a `class`

The `OrderNumberPrinter` `struct` really should be a `class` because it has `private` member data.  See [C.8](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rc-class)

### Use `std::size_t` rather than `int`

The values `m_len` and `m_current` should both probably be `std::size_t` rather than `int`, not least because they are compared to `num` and initialized with `list.size()` which are both explicitly `std::size_t`.

### Exercise all functions

There is no way that the destructor ever gets called in the current code because there is no exit condition in the code.  For that reason, how do you know if it works?  I'd ask that for an interview.  I'd also ask why `w.joinable()` is tested before calling `w.join()`.  Is there a circumstance in which `w.joinable()` will return `false`?

### Think about further derivation

What would happen if a user derived from this class?  I'd recommend either declaring the destructor as `virtual` or declaring the class `final` to prevent derivation.

### Be clear about what each mutex is locking

The name `m_printLock` suggests that the shared resource being protected is `std::cout`.  If we used `std::basic_osyncstream` as suggested in a comment, would you still need a mutex?  If so, what would it then be locking?  Generally, I like to have each mutex just lock one thing because it simplifies maintenance and clarifies the intent to other programmers.

Comment: Thank you so much for the code review. Can you recommend me what to do with calling destructor in this example? I want to call it. I can add signal handler (for example, `SIGINT`), `m_run` variable flag to `OrderNumberPrinter` and stop method that will set m_run to false. Talking about your question: there is no circumstance in which join returns joinable.

Comment: Talking about `m_printLock`, yes, the name of this mutex isn't so good. This mutex should lock step increment, to be more precise  `m_current` change. Also `cout` object access should be locked, otherwise, thread sanitizer will warn about data races. If I want to print to stdout using`std::cout` what should I do in this case?

Comment: One idea for ending would be to pass in a `limit` value to count down the number of messages printed.  For the `m_printLock`, I think it's OK to leave it as it is in the code; mostly I was just asking the kinds of questions that come up in interviews.  A comment in the code about exactly what is being locked would be sufficient.